# how to collect data to array from json apicall response (execute('GET', $url)

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I got this API sample code from my webshop provider. It's use to get data from my webshop database directly:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/apicall.php';
$username = 'extreme';
$apiKey = 'xxxx';
$apiCall = new ApiCall($username, $apiKey);
$apiCall->setFormat('json');
$url = 'extreme.api.shoprenter.hu/products/cHJvZHVjdC1wcm9kdWN0X2lkPTQ0NDE=';
$response = $apiCall->execute('GET', $url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response->getParsedResponseBody());
```

The output looks like this:
http://data.extremeaudio.hu/api/product.php

My task is to gather data from this output into an array or something, so i can use it to refresh my product prices dinamically in a html based javascript banner page here:

http://data.extremeaudio.hu/tv/

So please guide me, how can I collect this part:

```
[price] => 23621.2600
```

to display the actual price inside the banners.

I'm absolutely NOT a php expert - as you see - so please if you help, use examples or detailed comments.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $response->getParsedResponseBody()['price'] ?

Comment: @splash58 is that supported in OP's PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$response->getParsedResponseBody()` you have an array.

Save this array to an var `$var = $response->getParsedResponseBody();`.

Then you can access `price` via `$var['price'];`;